# How to enable Nested Virtualization on an existing Google cloud VM instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to enable Nested Virtualization on a existing VM instance. The VM is on the Intel Haswell CPU platform so Nested Virtualization is possible.

Now I've read this support article at Google: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances

Under the first section *Enabling nested virtualization on an instance* it says the following:

> Create a boot disk from a public image or from a custom image with an
>   operating system. ***Alternatively, you can skip this step and apply
>   the license to an existing disk from one of your VM instances.***

However I can't figure out how to apply the Nested Virtualization license to an existing VM instance. The only steps described are for new disks and I want to apply it to an existing disk.

My question is: How can I enable Nested Virtualization on a existing Google Cloud Instance?

Thanks in advance,
Hugo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will share with you instructions on how to enable Nested Virtualization on an existing GCP VM instance. More detailed steps are described [in the article you shared](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances).

1. From your existing VM instance, you [should already have a boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-root-persistent-disks) in your project. If not, you should create a boot disk from that VM instance.
2. Using the boot disk from that existing VM instance, please create a custom image with the special license key required for virtualization.

   a- If you are creating an image using the `gcloud` command-line tool, provide the following license URL using the `--licenses` flag:

https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/vm-options/global/licenses/enable-vmx

For example, the following command creates an image named `nested-vm-image` from an example disk named `disk1`:

```
$ gcloud compute images create \
    nested-vm-image \ 
    --source-disk disk1 \
    --source-disk-zone us-central1-b \ 
    --licenses "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/vm-options/global/licenses/enable-vmx"
```

b- If you are using the API, please include the licenses property in your API request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/global/images
{ 
    "licenses": [
        "projects/vm-options/global/licenses/enable-vmx"
    ], 
    "name": "nested-vm-image", 
    "sourceDisk": "zones/us-central1-b/disks/disk1" 
}
```

where [PROJECT_ID] is your project ID.